# systemd: how to set default log level for messages on stdout/stderr?

Tags: linux, logging, systemd

I am running an application as a systemd service. Application logs its output to stdout following systemd logging rules - prepending each log message with <x> where x is priority (log level).

```
<6> this is info
<7> this is debug
<4> this is warning
```

What I want is to store only priority <= 6 to journal because I run on flashdisk. I don't wan't to store debug messages and also messages/"trash" that is not marked with <>.

Seems not to be a problem - MaxLevelStore=info.

BUT - the problem is that that "trash" written to stdout is marked as priority=6 (info) by default and is also stored inside journal db. What I want is to mark it as debug (7) by default, so from following output:

```
<6> this is info
<7> this is debug
this is some trash
<4> this is warning
```

... will only ...

```
<6> this is info
<4> this is warning
```

... be stored to journal.

Can't find in all docs I have if/how is this possible. Anybody?

Thank you

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Do you have a reference (like docs or source code) which points to this "<level_number> my log message" format for printing logs to systemd/journal in the stdout?

Answer (score 7):

You want to use`SyslogLevel=debug` in the `[Service]` section of your service. This will cause all messages that aren't prefixed by the priority to default to having a level of debug (7).

Documentation:
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#SyslogLevel=